# When an induced charge (i.e. polarization) takes place, what is the velocity of the process? Is it dependent upon the permittivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

In a classic demonstration of inducing a charge on a dielectric, the latter is exposed to an external field. There is a resulting charge separation in the dielectric. What is the velocity of propagation of this charge separation? Is it the velocity of electromagnetic waves in the dielectric i.e. "the speed of light"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is heavily dependent on the material. For most materials the electric constant $\epsilon$ is very far from being a simple scaling factor, it has a complicated frequency response so that we write $\vec{D}(\omega) = \epsilon(\omega) \vec{E}(\omega)$ (assuming an isotropic and local medium, so that $\epsilon$ is scalar and local). For example, the [Sellmeier equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation) (with different coefficients for different materials) describes many materials at optical frequencies very well and it is simply a set of resonances, which you can think of as arising from electrons on springs (*i.e.* bound to molecules) so they undergo forced harmonic motion in response to the electric field. The "speed" of their reaction is set, as with any forced harmonic oscillator, by the strength of their binding (the "spring constant") and their mass (inertia). Recall that each electron only has to shift a very short distance to beget the dielectric effect, so its not like electrons have to rush all over the place to beget the charge shifts: the polarization essentially arises from the appearance and alignment of dipoles. You should keep the system of electrons on springs rather than electrons running all over the place in your head. As the field's frequency rises, charge separation and polarization stay pretty much in phase with the electric field until you get nearish the first resonance.

The Sellmeier model when losses are added is called the Ketteler-Helmholtz model and models essentially a system of damped harmonic oscillators.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that in metals the electrons, which are free to move, have a different reponse ie they travel with the drift velocity for a static appled field. When the applied field oscillates then the "plasma" oscillates?

Comment: Pretty much. You then need to look at the Drude-Lorentz model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model